# what are depended package for install WeasyPrint in dockerfile?

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile, weasyprint

I install WeasyPrint and config it for views.py ,urls.py,admin.py and my template.

when i want convert html page to pdf , i have this error :

```
(process:7): Pango-CRITICAL **: 13:27:29.635: pango_font_get_hb_font: assertion 'PANGO_IS_FONT (font)' failed
base_shop_web_1 exited with code 245
```

my Dockerfile is :

```bash
FROM python:alpine

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code

ADD requirements.txt /code/

WORKDIR /code

RUN apk add --update --no-cache curl jq py3-configobj py3-pip py3-setuptools python3 python3-dev 

RUN apk add cairo-dev pango-dev gdk-pixbuf-dev py-lxml shared-mime-info openjpeg-dev freetype-dev \
    libpng-dev gettext libxml2-dev libxslt-dev

RUN apk add make automake libffi-dev gcc linux-headers g++ py3-brotli  musl-dev postgresql-dev zlib-dev jpeg-dev 

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt  

EXPOSE 8000

COPY . /code/
```

what things i shoud to add dockerfile ?

Answer (score 0):

for install reportlab for python:alpine we should install py-reportlab, not reportlab .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).